# PayPal don't dislay Pay with CC or DC with VitueMart

Tags: php, paypal, virtuemart

I have a prolem with PayPal, maybe anyone has experienced the same problem and knows the solution.

I'm using VirtueMart that has built in 2 PayPal payment methods Legacy and API. I'm using Legacy.

I read how to set up VirtueMart for PayPal (before that I had done it myself because it's very simple), only put the email, rest are optional.

The result I want to get on the PayPal page is let customers pay without registering - but I can't get it working. I'm always getting Log-in or Register.

I read the manual for PayPal - it says for Business accounts, like mine, there's a radio button Account Optional that has to be ON. I have it - but it still doesn't display Pay without Registering.

So, maybe someone can help me out with this one :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Country, as far as I could figure out. Paypal lists my country in the official Manual - but it's still not avaliable.